# Reentrant lock implementation detail

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, reentrantlock, java-15

I am trying to understand a particular detail in `ReentrantLock::lock` method. I am looking at it and seeing it as:

```
final void lock() {
   if (!initialTryLock()) {
       acquire(1);
   }
}
```

So first it tries this method : `initialTryLock` (I will look in `NonfairSync`), which does this:

- it does a `compareAndSwap(0, 1)`, meaning if no one holds the lock (`0`) and I can grab it (`1`), I hold the lock now.
- if the above fails, it checks if the thread requesting the lock is the owner already.
- if that fails it returns `false`, meaning I could not acquire the lock.

Let's assume the above failed. It then goes on and calls `acquire` in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`:

```
public final void acquire(int arg) {
    if (!tryAcquire(arg))
        acquire(null, arg, false, false, false, 0L);
}
```

It calls `tryAcquire` first in `NonfairSync`:

```
protected final boolean tryAcquire(int acquires) {
    if (getState() == 0 && compareAndSetState(0, acquires)) {
        setExclusiveOwnerThread(Thread.currentThread());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can see that it tries to acquire the lock *again*, though the `initialTryLock` already failed. In theory, this `tryAcquire` could have simply returned `false`, right?

I see this as a potential retry, because between the calls of `initialTryLock` and `tryAcquire`, the lock might have been released. The benefit of this might be that because the next operation (after `tryAcquire`) fails, is the expensive enqueue of this thread. So I guess this makes sense (to retry) because of that?

Comment: which version of java src are you mentioning?

Comment: @Andrea my bad, I was looking at jdk-15; if that matters.

Comment: In java 12 ReentrantLock::lock calls directly sync.acquire(1) and the function initialTryLock does not exist. So the code you mention was introduced recently. If someone would investigate, he should refer to the correct java version

Comment: @Andrea good point. I added the proper tag. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65964546).

> `tryAcquire` could have simply returned false, right?

No.

This implementation:

```java
boolean tryAcquire(int acquires) {
  return false;
}
```

would break the work of `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`.

The reason is that `tryAcquire()` is the only way to take the lock in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`.

Even [`acquire()` in the end uses `tryAcquire()`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java#l671).

So if `tryAcquire()` always returned `false` then `acquire()` would never acquire the lock.

And `acquire()` is used when several threads contend for the lock.

Comment: I saw the usage of `tryAcquire` in `acquire`, but as far as I can see [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java#l676) it's perfectly OK for it to fail, i.e.: `acquired` to be `false`. that threw me off a little bit, initially. I looked at the code now that you mentioned a bit closer, and if `tryAcquire` would return `false`, any extending class of `AbstractQueueSynchronizer` could not acquire the lock for an `ExclusiveNode`, indeed. thank you, it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

- `initialTryLock()` contains reentrancy functionality:

  - javadoc:

    ```java
    /**
    * Checks for reentrancy and acquires if lock immediately
    * available under fair vs nonfair rules. Locking methods
    * perform initialTryLock check before relaying to
    * corresponding AQS acquire methods.
    */
    abstract boolean initialTryLock();
    ```
  - source code in `NonfairSync`:

    ```java
    final boolean initialTryLock() {
        Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
        if (compareAndSetState(0, 1)) { // first attempt is unguarded
            setExclusiveOwnerThread(current);
            return true;
        } else if (getExclusiveOwnerThread() == current) {
            int c = getState() + 1;
            if (c < 0) // overflow
                throw new Error("Maximum lock count exceeded");
            setState(c);
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
    ```

    Here:

    - the 1st `if` checks if the lock is taken (and takes the lock if it is free)
    - the 2nd `if` checks if the taken lock belongs to the current thread  — this is the reentrancy logic.
- `tryAcquire()` must be implemented by any class extending `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`

  - what the method must do is described in its javadoc in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`

  ```java
    /**
     * Attempts to acquire in exclusive mode. This method should query
     * if the state of the object permits it to be acquired in the
     * exclusive mode, and if so to acquire it.
     * ...
     */
    protected boolean tryAcquire(int arg) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
  ```

  - implementation in `NonfairSync` does exactly that (and doesn't contain reentrancy functionality):

  ```java
  /**
  * Acquire for non-reentrant cases after initialTryLock prescreen
  */
  protected final boolean tryAcquire(int acquires) {
      if (getState() == 0 && compareAndSetState(0, acquires)) {
          setExclusiveOwnerThread(Thread.currentThread());
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

Comment: so what stops `NonfairSync::tryAcquire` to return `false`? it is a non-public class with a non-public method.

Comment: From [user15110003](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15110003/user15110003): `tryAcquire()` is used in several places inside `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`.  
In the place you found it would be fine if `tryAcquire()` did nothing and returned `false`.  
But in other places inside `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` it would break `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` if `tryAcquire()` didn't adhere its contract in javadoc for `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer::tryAcquire`.

Comment: @dan1st right. I hope I missed it, but can you spot any code flows where `tryAcquire` is not followed by `acquire` in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`? I do understand obeying to the javadoc, but returning `false` would not be a violation of that. I mean the default implementation even throws an Exception. Besides the javadoc says : _Attempts to acquire in exclusive mode_, which `initialTryLock` already did via `if (compareAndSetState(0, 1)`. And btw you gotta tag me with `@` when posting a comment